# RegExp, how to replace a string not containing a word?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace a string using `regular expressions`, and this string musn't contain a specific word.

Here is the string :

```
$string = 'mysql_fetch_array( $stmt = mysql_query( $query ) );' // Shouldn't match
$string = 'mysql_fetch_array( $stmt ) );' // Should match
```

The regex :

```
preg_replace('/^(.*)mysql_fetch_(.*)\([ ]?.*(?!mysql_query).*[ ]?\)(.*)$/', $value, $string);
```

But both strings match the above expression.

How can I replace the second string only ?

Comment: so a string containing `mysql_query( $query )` shouldnt match ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$arr = array('mysql_fetch_array( $stmt = mysql_query( $query ) );', 'mysql_fetch_array( $stmt ) );');
$value = 'NEW($1)';
foreach($arr as $string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/^.*?mysql_fetch_[^(]+\( *(\$\w+)(?!.* = mysql_query).*\);$/', $value, $string);
    echo $string,"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
mysql_fetch_array( $stmt = mysql_query( $query ) );
NEW($stmt)
```

Comment: It's working but I want to catch `$stmt` with parentheses, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex. PHP has a string replace method: Regex is always the last choice you should make.

```
str_replace("[new sub]", "[old sub]", "[whole string]");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: "Regex is always the last choice you should make." **Why?** I mean, it's pretty powerful. Why make it the last choice?